# Dictionary appended into a list

Tags: python

Learning Python and am looking for a way to print out the items in the dictionary to include the dictionary name. I can print the items in the dictionary but not the name.

Trying to get this output:

Name: Sparky
Type: Dog
Owner: Bracken

```
pets = []
sparky = {'type' : 'dog', 'owner' : 'bracken',}
pets.append(sparky)

spots = {'type' : 'cheeta', 'owner' : 'jim',}
pets.append(spots)

sebastian = {'type' : 'cat', 'owner' : 'tyra',}
pets.append(sebastian)

for pet in pets:
print(pets)
```

Comment: it sounds like what you actually want to do is store the dictionaries containing the pets into a dictionary. Something like `pets['sparky'] = { ... }`

Comment: Most objects in Python don't have names, per se. Likely you think that when you bind `{'type' : 'dog', 'owner' : 'bracken'}` to `sparky` (i.e., when you write `sparky = {'type' : 'dog', 'owner' : 'bracken'}`, you're thinking that `sparky` is the name of the object. This isn't true. If you want your objects to have a name in the way you're thinking, you should consider building a class. An alternative, as suggested by @Hamms, is to make your `pets` object a dictionary keyed by the name of each pet.

Comment: `dict` objects *don't have names*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for a beginner that might be a confusing way to say that names refer to values unidirectionally.

Answer (score 6):

The variable name is not part of the dictionary data. Just add a new key/value pair `'name': 'sparky'` etc. to the new dog dictionaries. Eg. `sparky = {'name': 'sparky', 'type': 'dog', 'owner': 'bracken',}`.

Answer (score 1):

to print a dict, you can format method.
 1. iterate list of pets
 2. pass dict to format method, 
 3. Note: make sure that you include name: pet_name in the dict.

```
for pet in pets:
    print("Name: {name} Type: {type} Owner: {owner}".format(**pet))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pets = []
sparky = {'name': 'sparky', 'type': 'dog', 'owner': 'bracken',}
pets.append(sparky)

spots = {'name': 'spots', 'type' : 'cheeta', 'owner' : 'jim',}
pets.append(spots)

sebastian = {'name': 'sebastian', 'type' : 'cat', 'owner' : 'tyra',}
pets.append(sebastian)

for pet in pets:
    print("Name: {name} Type: {type} Owner: {owner}".format(**pet))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using dictionary instead of list, you can do this:

```
pets = {}
pets['sparky'] = {'type' : 'dog', 'owner' : 'bracken',}
pets['spots'] = {'type' : 'cheeta', 'owner' : 'jim',}
pets['sebastian'] = {'type' : 'cat', 'owner' : 'tyra',}

for k,v in pets.items():
    print('Name:', k,' '.join([ '{}:{}'.format(i,j) for (i,j) in v.items()]))
```

**Output**

```
Name: spots type:cheeta owner:jim
Name: sebastian type:cat owner:tyra
Name: sparky type:dog owner:bracken
```